# How to set LaTeX syntax to "ConTeXt" in vimrc

Tags: filetype-tex, syntax-highlighting, vimrc

**TL;DR:** How do I permanently and persistently `:set syntax=context` for `*.tex` files?

---

I've been using `vim` for a LaTeX project, with [monokai-tasty](https://github.com/patstockwell/vim-monokai-tasty) as the colour scheme.

The default syntax highlighting seems to be TeX Highlighting

```
:set syntax=tex
```

I personally prefer ConTeXt Highlighting

```
:set syntax=context
```

but cannot figure out how to make it stick for all `*.tex` buffers, or between sessions.

I've tried several ways of getting this to work, mostly through `vimrc`, though none of them have. Most recently I created `~/.vim/ftdetect/tex.vim` containing

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex set syntax=context
```

My `vimrc` can be [seen here](https://github.com/BrokenFlows/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc), in case there are any obvious collisions with what I'm trying to do there.

---

Not sure if I've given enough information. I am, of course, happy to add any more if it's not enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the variable `g:tex_flavor`. Put this in your vimrc file:

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'context'
```

For more information, see `:help g:tex_flavor`.

Comment: Should that be in `~/.vim/ftdetect/tex.vim` or in `vimrc`? Should it follow something like `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex let g:tex_flavor = 'context'`.

Comment: This seems to work when loading a file but upon rerunning `:source ~/.vimrc` it reverts to the same result as `:set syntax=tex` so perhaps it isn't working at all?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer: "Put this in your vimrc file".

Comment: To clarify my second comment, which you seem to have skipped over: having tried that, it isn’t working as I would expect or hope.

Comment: I did not skip over it, but you are not being very clear. You are not describing what you are doing in detail, you are not describing what you are expecting/hoping. To be more helpful, I would need to be able to reproduce your problem, and based on what you have provided so far, I can't.

Comment: I would like `*.tex` files to have ConTeXt highlighting. I would expect, once the correct solution was implemented, that if I ran the vim command `:source ~/.vimrc` while viewing a `*.tex` file that the syntax highlighting would be correct. 


If I add `let g:tex_flavor = 'context'`, and do what I described above, I get a result matching the command `:set syntax=tex` where I hoped it would match `:set syntax=context`.

Comment: You should not need to do `:source ~/.vimrc`, since this is done when Vim starts. The file should be correctly highlighted when you open it, not when you source your vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the syntax always to `context`, just put this in your vimrc:

`autocmd BufReadPost *.tex set syntax=context`